Hibernate does not find sequence across multiple databases of same server when ddl-auto is set to validate
Environment:
Spring Boot version: 3.2.1 with Hibernate-Core 6.4.1.Final
Also tested with 3.3.1 with Hibernate-Core 6.5.2.Final
Database: MS SQL Server with multiple accessible databases
Issue:
I have a setup where I need to map a sequence to the @Id field of an entity using @GeneratedValue and @SequenceGenerator annotations. The entity itself is mapped to Database A (it’s a View), but the sequence it relies on is located in Database B (which also store the Table). I specify the "catalog" and "schema" parameters in the @SequenceGenerator annotation to point to the correct location of the sequence in Database B.
When I configure my Spring Boot API with spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto set to validate, Hibernate throws an error at startup (from class AbstractSchemaValidator), indicating that it cannot find the sequence. It seems to only query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES of the database that the connection is opened for, rather than checking across all specified catalogs in the entity mappings.
Switching ddl-auto to none avoids this error at startup, and the application runs fine with the sequence being correctly utilized at runtime.
Expected Behavior:
Hibernate should correctly locate the sequence in Database B when the catalog and schema are properly specified in the @SequenceGenerator annotation, even when ddl-auto is set to validate.
Actual Behavior:
Hibernate fails to find the sequence unless ddl-auto is set to none, suggesting it does not fully honor the catalog settings in multi-database environments during schema validation. This throws the error message :

Schema-validation: missing sequence ["B.schema_from_B.my_sequence"]

Code Example :

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_view", schema = "schema_from_A", catalog = "A")
public class ViewEntity {
   
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "my_seq_generator")
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "my_seq_generator", catalog = "B", schema = "schema_from_B", sequenceName = "my_sequence")
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Integer id;


}

Configuration YML :
Here's an extract of my configuration

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://<ip_of_server>;databaseName=A;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        default_catalog: A
        default_schema: my_schema_A
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate



I don't understand what is the "pu" in your sentence.
For the First point, I can't set multiple database settings. Or I don't know how from my configuration YML.

Hibernate may not support multiple databasesas ddl-auto: validate only looks for INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES as given in connection URL and not @SequenceGenerator given by you.
What can be done is create your own schema validation and set ddl-auto: none. Run a bean that checks the schema validity at runtime from target catalog.
For example:
try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
         Statement stmt = connection.createStatement()) {

        String query = "SELECT sequence_name FROM B.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES WHERE sequence_name = 'my_sequence' AND sequence_schema = 'schema_from_B'";
        ResultSet resultset = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        if (!resultset.next()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Schema-validation: invalid/missing sequence [B.schema_from_B.my_sequence]");
        }

